# Is Lookup function support two primary key in RDLC Report?

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-2012, rdl

Actual, I use Lookup function for getting the matching value by using single primary key.

According MSDN, This is syntax of Lookup function

```
  =Lookup(source_expression, destination_expression, result_expression, dataset)
```

But I have a problem becuase 
the second parameter(destination_expression) has two primary key 
like these

[image]

I need to know that how to use Lookup function for two primary key?
(Editing SQL and datatable will be the last way.)

___________________EXAMPLE______________________________

**SALE_INVOICE table** is assigned to Tablix1

(SALE_INVOICE table has Two Foreign Key including with

CUSTOMER_CODE and CUSTOMER_BRANCH_SEQ)

[image]

and I need to display NAME or ADRRESS which it get from CUSTOMER_BRANCH
which this parent table has two primary key.

Below figure is **CUSTOMER_BRANCH table**
[image]

It's has two primary key.

Comment: Somebody Help me please

Comment: Maybe with a calculated field with the concatenation of both fields as a surogate key for the lookup?

Comment: @ThanapipatPacharatanakoson How you are getting the values of two different datasets (DatasetA and DatasetB) in your tablix?

Comment: Because of Database was designed like that. Some Table has two PrimaryKey. And I know I can resolve this problem by joining both of datasets before using in report. But I attempt to make report without editing datatable. (My Team use Data Source Configuration Wizard for creating datatable.) So they need to avoid editing any Datasource.

Comment: I understand that part. My question is you have a tablix(Table) in your SSRS report. How you are getting two values from two different datasets (DatasetA and DatasetB). If we can found out that then we can identify how can we get the value for the third dataset (Dataset C).

Comment: @ThanapipatPacharatanakoson It is possible to do such lookup. To provide better answer can you provide some more info on how you will get  the B_Code value? If possible shows some sample data.

Comment: i'm sorry.I don't understand your question. A dataset was assign to tablix has two foreign key.
First is CUSTOMER_CODE and second is CUSTOMER_BRANCH_SEQ

two foreign-key can find NAME from CUSTOMER_BRANCH table which this parent table has two primary. 

I edited for adding example